# Why linking html webpage title appears differently on mobile device?

Tags: html, github

I have created a `github.io` profile with `.html`  files.

The profile looks good on PC.

However, in on mobile device (iPad), it doesn't show the tile of the linking HTML files during the navigations

For example; in my `index.html` I have

```
<li>
  <a href="Symposia & Workshops.html">Symposia & Workshops</a>
</li>
```

even though on PC it shows the full title Symposia & Workshops on the mobile device, it hides the title.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use media query for different screen sizes
This link might be helpful for you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries